# pass subreport jrdatasource for each row during exporting main report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have to print a sub report for each row in main report, but the problem is I got my data for sub report only when I am returning a field value for one of the column (`Subreport` depends upon the value returned for that field value in each row) in main report.

I read jasper reports do not support typical data types in field values (`$F{abc}` can hold only limited data types like string, number etc) like `Arrays`, `List`, `Collection` or `JRDataSource`.

These complex data types are supported by Parameters but parameter values should be passed to main report during `JasperFillManager.fillreport()` function at that time I don't have data source for my sub report.

Is there any way by which I can pass my `JRDataSource` to sub report during exporting main report?

Is possible or not? If it is, then how?

Comment: Set net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource as datasource while create a subreprot. except this send your value using parameter. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In report designer click on the subreport and set Data Source Expression

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{List<YourObjectObject>})
```

And in main report you can create `List<YourObjectObject>`